# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, Python

Tags: python, list

I need to display the number of vowels in the entered text, if they are in the text

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
a = 0
e = 0
y = 0
u = 0
o = 0
i = 0
word = input("Введите текст: ")
word1 = list(word)
print(word1)
for j in word1:
    if word1[j] == "a":
        a += 1
    elif word1[j] == "e":
        e += 1
    elif word1[j] == "y":
        y += 1
    elif word1[j] == "u":
        u += 1
    elif word1[j] == "o":
        o += 1
    elif word1[j] == "i":
        i += 1
if a != 0:
    print("a:", a)
if e != 0:
    print("e:", e)
if y != 0:
    print("y:", y)
if u != 0:
    print("u:", u)
if o != 0:
    print("o:", o)
if i != 0:
    print("i:", i)
```

Comment: when you do  `for j in word1` you iterate over each character un the `word1` meaning `j` will be a letter, not a number. So when you try to access `word1[j]` you actually try something like `word1['a']` and not word1[0] like you probably think

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate.

Comment: What you get from input is a string. Putting it in a list won't turn it into a list of characters. And your code still makes no sense. Anyway, the problem here is that `word1` is a list and `j` is a string. You cannot use a string as list index. You might consider changing it to a dictionary if you want to do it in this way.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over a string it returns the characters and not the positions.

For example:

```
for _c in 'test':
    print(_c)
```

will result in:

```
t
e
s
t
```

You should change it to:

```
for j, _c in enumerate(word1):
    ...
```

What enumerate does is adding a counter to the element you are iterating on, you can find more info [here](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/)